Will new 6.1 kernel packages be released?
I use 6.1 lts kernel, and the last update of 22.04 repository was about 2 weeks ago. Does one wait for new 6.1 kernel packages?

AskUbuntu (this site) is all volunteers. We answer (for free) questions about Ubuntu. Canonical, a for-profit company packages and releases Ubuntu. They've not the same.

You can delete question if it is not for this site.

I politely disagree with the downvotes and the close votes. Asking about published policy of kernel release seems a valid and on-topic question.

6.1 is a supported Debian kernel, are you using an OEM kernel of Ubuntu?  or have installed a testing kernel (as they do NOT get upgraded security fixes/patches). If you are using an OEM kernel that was installed by your system (ie. OEM), then you will get security fixes; however if you installed the 6.1 yourself; all security patches became your responsibility as you opted to use a testing or Debian kernel.

@guiverc I had 6.1.0-1036-oem kernel. Now I have installed 6.5.0-generic as user535733 suggested.

I wouldn't be worried about using the https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy-updates/linux-buildinfo-6.1.0-1036-oem kernel, as it still looks the latest & supported to me... The last change I see was Mon, 11 Mar 2024 17:31:52 (to fix CVE-2023-6039); but GA + HWE + OEM options do exist for LTS releases of Ubuntu... You can use whichever best suits your needs.   FYI:  Ian's answer may have differed if you'd mentioned you were using an OEM kernel in your question, not just 6.1 kernel

I will follow the changes in the repository. If new 6.1-oem appears I will change back maybe. As far as I understand, I have installed automatic update of hwe kernel now. It looks working. GA kernel doesn't work with my wifi card.

Most users use the GA OR* HWE kernel stacks.. as OEM are hardware specific kernels; and one benefit of using the more common kernel is blogs etc. write about common stuff far more than OEM... Some Ubuntu ISOs can install using OEM, others cannot.. but I have no idea when an OEM kernel will update, except for after CVEs are fixed (HWE kernels change over time for two years; ie. current 6.5 HWE will upgrade to 6.8 from 24.04 soon...)

As of 2024-05-03,
The current 22.04 HWE kernel is 6.5 (not 6.1).
The current 22.04 GA kernel remains 5.15.
That you are running 6.1 suggests a problem with your system -- your system should have upgraded to 6.5 automatically.

Please ensure your 22.04 system has the linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04 package installed, and that your apt updates and apt upgrades are not outputting errors.

No supported version of 22.04 uses the 6.1 kernel, so there won't be any further releases for it.

I have installed 6.5.0-28-generic
